# How to share data in `AWS Step Functions` without passing it between the steps

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I use `AWS Step Functions` and have the following workflow

[image: AWS Step Functions workflow]

**initStep** - It's a lambda function handler, that gets some data and sends it to `SQS` for external service.

```
activity = os.getenv('ACTIVITY')
queue_name = os.getenv('QUEUE_NAME')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  event['my_activity'] = activity
  data = json.dumps(event)

  # Retrieving a queue by its name
  sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
  queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)

  queue.send_message(MessageBody=data, MessageGroupId='messageGroup1' + str(datetime.time(datetime.now())))

  return event
```

**validationWaiting** - It's an `activity` that waits for an answer from the external service that include the data.

**complete** - It's a lambda function handler, that uses the data from the `initStep`.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  email = event['email'] if 'email' in event else None
  data = event['data'] if 'data' in event else None

  client = boto3.client(service_name='ses')
  to = email.split(', ')
  message_conrainer = {'Subject': {'Data': 'Email from step functions'},
           'Body': {'Html': {
               'Charset': "UTF-8",
               'Data': """<html><body>
                            <p>""" + data """</p>
                            </body> </html> """
           }}}

  destination = {'ToAddresses': to,
               'CcAddresses': [],
               'BccAddresses': []}

  return client.send_email(Source=from_addresses,
                         Destination=destination,
                         Message=message_container)
```

It does work, but the problem is that I'm sending full data from the `initStep` to external service, just to pass it later to `complete`. Potentially more steps can be added.

I believe it would be better to share it as some sort of global data (of current step function), that way I could add or remove steps and data would still be available for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer of [Marcin Sucharski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845487/how-to-share-data-in-aws-step-functions-without-passing-it-between-the-steps/54852045#54852045) I've came up with my own solution.

I needed to use `Type: Task` since `initStep` is a lambda, which sends SQS.

I didn't needed `InputPath` in `ValidationWaiting`, but only `ResultPath`, which store the data received in activity.

I work with [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework, here is my final solution:

```
StartAt: initStep
States: 
  initStep:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:init-step
    Next: ValidationWaiting
  ValidationWaiting:
    Type: Task
    ResultPath: $.validationOutput
    Resource: arn:aws:states:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:validationActivity
    Next: Complete
    Catch:
      - ErrorEquals:
        - States.ALL
      ResultPath: $.validationOutput
      Next: Complete
  Complete:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:complete-step
    End: true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `InputPath` and `ResultPath`. In `initStep` you would only send necessary data to external service (probably along with some unique identifier of Execution). In the `ValidaitonWaiting` step you can set following properties (in State Machine definition):

- `InputPath`: What data will be provided to `GetActivityTask`. Probably you want to set it to something like `$.execution_unique_id` where `execution_unique_id` is field in your data that external service uses to identify Execution (to match it with specific request during `initStep`).
- `ResultPath`: Where output of ValidationWaiting Activity will be saved in data. You can set it to `$.validation_output` and json result from external service will be present there.

This way you can send to external service only data that is actually needed by it and you won't lose access to any data that was previously (before `ValidationWaiting` step) in the input.

For example, you could have following definition of the State Machine:

```
{
  "StartAt": "initStep",
  "States": {
    "initStep": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "executionId": "some:special:id",
        "data": {},
        "someOtherData": {"value": "key"}
      },
      "Next": "ValidationWaiting"
    },
    "ValidationWaiting": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "InputPath": "$.executionId",
      "ResultPath": "$.validationOutput",
      "Result": {
        "validationMessages": ["a", "b"]
      },
      "Next": "Complete"
    },
    "Complete": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I've used `Pass` states for `initStep` and `ValidationWaiting` to simplify the example (I haven't run it, but it should work). `Result` field is specific to `Pass` task and it is equivalent to the result of your Lambda functions or Activity.

In this scenario `Complete` step would get following input:

```
{
  "executionId": "some:special:id",
  "data": {},
  "someOtherData": {"value": key"},
  "validationOutput": {
    "validationMessages": ["a", "b"]
  }
}
```

So the result of `ValidationWaiting` step has been saved into `validationOutput` field.

Comment: Can you please clarify how exactly to use `InputPath` and `ResultPath`? Should they both be added into config of `ValidationWaiting`? Can you please add code for example?

Answer (score 1):

Here a short and simple solution with InputPath and ResultPath. My Lambda Check_Ubuntu_Updates return a list of instance ready to be updated. This list of instances is received by the step Notify_Results, then it use this data. Remember that if you have several ResultPath in your Step Function and you need more than 1 input in a step you can use InputPath only with $.

```
{
  "Comment": "A state machine that check some updates systems available.",
  "StartAt": "Check_Ubuntu_Updates",
  "States": {
    "Check_Ubuntu_Updates": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:#############:function:Check_Ubuntu_Updates",
      "ResultPath": "$.instances",
      "Next": "Notify_Results"
    },
    "Notify_Results": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "InputPath": "$.instances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:#############:function:Notify_Results",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```